# Difference between importing css in index.html and styleUrls in Angular 5

Tags: css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular5

I use different css in my landing page component and dashboard component so either the landing page or dashboard does not work depending on css. When I remove from index.html these two lines:

```
  <link href="./assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="./assets/css/paper-dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

and in angular.cli I set:

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "assets/sass/paper-kit.scss",
        "assets/css/demo.css",
        "assets/css/nucleo-icons.css"
      ]
```

my component (landing page) works properly but dashboard doesn't. However when I add mentioned two lines to index.html and in angular.cli I set:

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ]
```

my landing page doesn't work properly however dashboard does. I set `styleUrls` in the way shown below however they don't seem to be working properly. Does anyone have an idea how can I solve my problem? I need to have both components working properly. It seems to me that I need to set css for every component separately as I have tried without results but I am not sure whether it is a good idea?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard-cmp',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    '../../assets/css/paper-dashboard.css',
    '../../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'
  ]
})
```

**UPDATE**

I noticed that when angular.cli styles looks in this way:

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "assets/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "assets/sass/paper-kit.scss",
    "assets/css/demo.css",
    "assets/css/nucleo-icons.css",
    "assets/css/paper-dashboard.css"
  ]
```

my dashboard component works properly however landing page doesn't. When I change styles to:

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "assets/sass/paper-kit.scss",
    "assets/css/demo.css",
    "assets/css/nucleo-icons.css",
    "assets/css/paper-dashboard.css"
  ]
```

my landing page component is working properly and dashboard doesn't. So I try something like this - in `dashboard.component.ts` I set styleUrls: `['./dashboard.component.css']` and in `dashboard.component.css` I add `@import url('/../../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css');`. Unfortunately still landing page is working properly and dashboard doesn't. Any ideas why?

Comment: Why would you add bootstrap.min.css to a component instead of your application in angular-cli.json?

Comment: Because when I use different css in my landing page and main panel so either the landing page or main panel does not work depending on css. So I decided to add these css separately to landing page component and main panel. Do you think that is not a good idea?

Comment: ../../assets  that would tell the browser to look outside the project folder. Maybe try  ../assets  maybe ./assets

Comment: @rickz But there is my assets directory. I updated my question and I explained my problem more clearly.

Comment: @JohnSmith I think your css path  for dashboard is incorrect. In which folder `paper-dashboard.css` is lying.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you are asking exactly. You mentionned `paper-dashboard.css` in your index.html, but you did not try adding it to angular-cli (you added `paper-kit.scss`) Do you also have any build error in the terminal console?

Comment: @David I updated the question. Any ideas how can I solve it?

Comment: 1. You need to define `not working`. 2. And do you actually have 2 bootstrap.min.css files, one in css and one in assets folder? 3. And no error in console ? 4.Should not it be you who know which css file is needed on your own app/components?

Answer (score 1):

Components are encapsulated magic, its like you own room rather than the whole house. When you paint only your room(component) with the paint that your parents decided for your house (index.html), the paints won't be visible outside.. when you wan to paint the house like your parents told you go for outside as a whole(index.html), or if you want customized room, paint only in your room(component)

Comment: I use different css in my landing page and main panel so either the landing page or main panel does not work depending on css. So I decided to add these css separately to landing page component and main panel. This is the equivalent of panting separately room in different way. However it doesn't work as I described it in question. Do you know how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In angular css have two scopes i.e global and component scope. Css defined in global scope is applied through out the application means in all components. For global scope include the css in `index.html` file or register in the `styles` section of `.angular-cli.json` file.

In angular-cli.json file

```
"styles": [
     "styles.css",
     "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ],
```

The styles specified in `@Component` metadata apply only within the template of that component.

In Component

```
styleUrls: [
    './paper-dashboard.css'
  ]
```

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Comment: I updated my question and I explained my problem more clearly. Any ideas how can I solve this?